# Keep Windows 10 start menu open when opening programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

To start off with: Holding the Windows key while clicking an app does **not** work (for me, that is).

I often need to open multiple programs at once from the start menu, which quickly turns into a tedious "open start, click program, open start, click program" routine. I assumed there would be an option to keep it open, so I tried the defaults (holding shift, ctrl, alt), didn't work. So I searched, and found that holding the windows key should work, but it doesn't. When I hold the windows key, this happens:

`Open Start Menu > Press and hold windows key > click app > start menu closes`

Upon releasing the windows key, the start menu opens again, but that's no better than just pressing the windows key after opening the first app.

I heavily suspect this has something to do with me using the fullscreen start menu. Does anyone know if this is the case, and if there's a way to keep the start menu open that does work?

Win10 Pro 10.0.19041

Comment: "Holding the Windows key while clicking an app does not work." - I have confirmed this actually does work. "I heavily suspect this has something to do with me using the fullscreen start menu." - It probably does, try disabling it, and finding out and editing your question.

Comment: Well, I would have tested that before, if I wasn't wary about that change messing up my entire start screen. It's already a PITA to get everything to stay in its place, and knowing windows, changing back to the regular start menu is going to mess with literally everything, so I was hoping that somebody who has experienced this before could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: You can make a shortcut that opens a succession of programs, might be an alternative for you.